# PHP simplexlsx class error Call to a member function dimension() while parsing xlsx

Tags: php, xlsx

During implementing class simplexlsx, while handling multiple sheets xlsx, I am getting an error:

Call to a member function `dimension()`:

```
$xlsx = SimpleXLSX::parse('countries_and_population.xlsx')
list( $num_cols, $num_rows ) = $xlsx->dimension();
```

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Over searching solution, Found dimension wont work for all xlxs. I replace the code :-

list( $cols, ) = $xlsx->dimension();

to

```
 $sheet =$xlsx->sheetNames();
    foreach($sheet as $ky=>$rw)
```

This works without any issue for all xlsx